# Updating SQL Server table over WAN from Access front end extremely slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I've got a small database that is hosted on our shared hosting account that I update through an access MDE file with Linked SQL Tables that gets run through task scheduler several times a day.

There's basically a small (under 20 row) user table, and a (presently) 1000 row data table.

Basically what my MDE 'front end' does is query the data out of my production database into temp tables in Access, delete the data from the two remote tables on my hosting provider and repopulate them.  So it's linked to two servers (one local and one remote) and I've read sometimes this can be problematic?

The data is slowly growing as more people are asking for access to their data, and at present the table with 1000 rows takes about 5 minutes to delete/repopulate using Linked Tables.

I've alleviated PART of the slowness by deleting the remote table data using SQL Passthrough. Deletion is near instantaneous.

However, I cannot do the same for APPEND because my temp data is only on the local MDE file and uploading it makes no sense (it wouldn't be quicker than it is now).

What I'd like to know is how can I speed up my APPEND queries to the remote server?  1000 rows of data (at something like 8 columns with few nulls) isn't very big when you put it in Excel (a couple hundred KB, MAYBE) so the APPEND taking this long makes no sense.

Both the User and Datatable have a timestamp data column, I've read this helps speed up Access -> SQL delete/appends because Access can check timestamps versus comparing row by row.

I'd love some suggestions on how to speed this up. It's not tons of data by any means.

```
Private Sub UpdateWebFunc()
On Error GoTo errors
   Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
   Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
   Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
   Dim rst2 As DAO.Recordset
   Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

   conn.ConnectionString = "Blah blah blah here"

   conn.Open

   Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("GetWebData")

   Set rst2 = qdf.OpenRecordset
   If Not rst2.BOF And Not rst2.EOF Then
   rst2.MoveFirst
   End If

   With cmd
    .CommandText = ”sp_UpdateWeb”
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .NamedParameters = True
    '.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", adInteger, adParamReturnValue, 0)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@SampID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@ReportTitle", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50)
   End With
   conn.BeginTrans
   Do Until rst2.EOF
    cmd.Parameters("@SampID") = rst2!SampID
    cmd.Parameters("@ReportTitle") = rst2!ReportTitle

    cmd.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
   rst2.MoveNext
   Loop
   conn.CommitTrans
   conn.Close
Set cmd = Nothing

   rst2.Close
   Set rst2 = Nothing

errors:
   MsgBox "Number: " & Err.Number & vbCr & " Description: " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

I keep getting stuck at the cmd.execute with a syntax error. I've tried to narrow it down to the two most important fields in the table to eliminate other conflicts.

**ERROR: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Syntax Error or access violation**

Here's my SP:

```
USE [MYDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpdateWeb] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @SampID VarChar(50),
    @ReportTitle VarChar(50)

AS
BEGIN
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[WEB] (SampID, ReportTitle) VALUES (@SampID, @ReportTitle)

END
```

Comment: You could try with another tool, to check if the problem is due to Access, or to your connection or host.

Comment: It's probably a bit of everything. I just ran an update via SQLMS that appended 5200 rows to a table on the remote host and it took about 6 minutes. :/

Comment: Have you tried using ADO for the insert? It might bypass Jet/ACE's wrong decisions in breaking down the batch INSERT into one INSERT per record (which is how Jet/ACE sends a batch INSERT to an ODBC server database).

Comment: @David I have not.  I'm just running queries to the linked ODBC tables.

Answer (score 2):

Why not attaching the remote server as a linked server to your production server, and bypassing Access completely ? I like Access, but in this case, it is unncecessary, and going direct will allow you to use SQL Agent to automate the task.

Comment: That's something I hadn't considered.  Though I'm not sure I know how to link tables in the SQL Management console.

Comment: not that complicated... google for "sql server linked" or see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx

Comment: Yeah I got that. :) Just trying to figure out best way to do things now.

Comment: @Mindflux: what's your result ?

Answer (score 1):

I take it that at the moment you are appending the data by using an access query? You might what to try the brute force method and open the local table in code and looping through that recordset firing off an insert statement for each row. You can wrap this all in a transaction to increase the performance and you could also try having a stored procedure on the SQL server that you call and pass parameters to as opposed to making the insert statement locally.

Code Sample Added*

You already know how to open the local table so I will use presto code for that. You can (and some would argue should) use DAO for the local access table. The stored procedure is then fired on an ADO connection like this

```
DIM cmd as NEW ADODB.Command
Dim dbCon as NEW ADODB.Connection

dbCon.ConnectionString = “Your connection string to the SQL server”
dbCon.Open

‘Setup the command
With CMD
 .CommandText=”spYour_stored_procedure”
 .CommandType=adCmdStoredProc
 .ActiveConnection=dbCon
 .NamedParameters=True
 .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@YourIntField", adInteger, adParamInput, 0, 123456)
 .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@YourTextField", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, “Badger”)
 ‘keep on adding parameters
End With
dbcon.BeginTrans
Do until YourDAORecordset.EOF
 cmd.Parameters(“@YourIntField”)= YourDAORecordset.YourField
 cmd.Parameters(“@YourTextField”)=” YourDAORecordset.YourOtherField
 cmd.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
 YourDAORecordset.MoveNext
Loop
dbcon.CommitTrans
Dbcon.close
Set cmd=nothing
```

---

Comment: Yes I'm appending using Access.  I'd think having several hundred inserts wouldn't be any better than my present situation would it? That's more or less what the query ends up doing anyway?

Comment: When you run a batch INSERT from Access to an ODBC linked database, Jet/ACE converts the batch INSERT into a series of INSERTs, one row per INSERT. This is why it's slow. But it's also exactly equivalent to walking the recordset and inserting one record at a time, so this suggestion won't speed things up at all.

Comment: @David that's precisely what I thought. Recommendations?

Comment: The part about having a server side stored procedure and calling that still stands and would help improve performance. Just make sure you setup the command object before the loop and only change the parameters during the loop. Also I should have said when walking the code to open the SQL server table using ADO.

Comment: Kevin.  Alright, I see where you're going with this.  I haven't dealt with any stored procedures like that, or ADO (I've used DAO loops before). Would you mind providing an example of both?

Comment: @MindFlux I have added an example to get you going in the right direction

Comment: Alright. So what sort of code do I need on the server for a stored procedure?

Comment: Also why is there the cmd.parameters append (with "Badger") and then the cmd.parameters(@Varname) below? This example here seems more straightforward: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vbscript/simple_sp_vb6.aspx?msg=2513034#xx2513034xx (3/4 of the way down where they update a table)

Comment: Updated the original topic to show what code I'm working with.

Comment: @Mindflux, yeah it’s a force of habit when I setup parameters but there is no need to. I just wrote that bit of code in notepad. At a quick glance I can’t see much wrong with your code but I will go away and recreate your environment and test. In the mean time can you confirm that it is not a security issue i.e. the account you are using has permission to execute that stored procedure

Comment: @Kevin: I can execute the SP through as passthrough query from access just fine.  I also tried tossing it some 'fake' data that I know would work.. such as cmd.Parameter("@SampID") = "dog" and similar for @ReportTitle but "cat" and it threw the same syntax error.

Comment: @Kevin: Got it going, my cmd.Commandtext = had the wrong quotation marks. They were a cut and paste from here. HEH

Comment: Ok, sadly to populate the whole data via this method (with a SP) took under 2 minutes for 944 rows.  If I go back to my 'old' method it took 59 seconds to populate the same table.Yech.

Comment: @Mindflux, hmmm nit so good. Just for shits and giggles can you try the loop you have above but instead of opening a recordset just loop through the SP code 944 times inserting random data. I want to see what the performance is for just firing the SP 944 times

Comment: I tried that as well and it took about the same time as the code you provided me.

Comment: Right so the bottle neck is the link to the server, just wanted to confirm that. I think you have found the base line for sending 944 records to the server over the WAN the “normal” way so unless we start doing some tricky stuff with asynchronous firing of your SP (which might not even help that much) then I would start looking at the WAN speed and/or the quality of the link (is it dropping packets causing retransmission?)

Comment: It may be a WAN issue, though we're on a set of bonded T-1's here.  I was wondering if the webhost is doing some throttling or something.